# What is the order in which oracle executes the update in statement?

Tags: oracle, sql-update, deadlock

I am trying to resolve a deadlock issue between two processes by trying to ensure that they lock the DB rows in order so one can finish before the other.

To do that, I am trying to determine how Oracle processes this statement:

```
update table_a
  set col_2 = 'hello'
  where col_1 in (1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10);
```

When this statement is executed, in what order does Oracle lock and update the rows? If you can point me in the direction on how to determine this, I'd be glad to do it myself.

I am posting this question because I did not find an answer in my Google search or elsewhere on this site, of course.

Comment: If Oracle is as ACID as it should, that order is an irrelevant implementation detail which should never matter. In short, the request should be considered as atomic, i.e. "instantaneous" from all clients' point of view.

Comment: Is the deadlock on a single SQL statement, or due to multiple statements within the same transaction?  If two processes make updates in a different sequence, you can get a deadlock.  Go read this link: http://www.oracle-base.com/articles/misc/deadlocks.php  You should have a trace file that shows the exact reason that the deadlock ocurred.

Comment: This may be the same as my question: http://stackoverflow.com/q/9216150/409172   TLDR - Oracle will likely process the same statement in a different order *if* the plans are different.  If the plans are the same, it's harder to say.  I think the order will be the same, others disagree, but nobody can prove it.