# SELECT FOR UPDATE with Subquery results in Deadlock

Tags: sql, oracle11g, database-deadlocks

I have query when executed from different session is resulting in deadlock.

```
TAB1 (ID, TARGET, STATE, NEXT) AND ID is primary key

Column ID is the primary key.
SELECT * 
FROM 
TAB1 WHERE NEXT = (SELECT MIN(NEXT) FROM TAB1 WHERE TARGET=? AND STATE=?) 
AND TARGET=? AND STATE=? FOR UPDATE
```

In the Oracle trace file, I see the statement:

```
DEADLOCK DETECTED
Current SQL statement for this session:
SELECT ID, TARGET, NEXT, STATE FROM TAB1 
WHERE NEXT=(SELECT MIN(NEXT) FROM TAB1 WHERE (TARGET='$any') AND ( STATE = 0))
AND (TARGET='$any')
AND (STATE = 0) FOR UPDATE
The following deadlock is not an ORACLE error. It is a
deadlock due to user error in the design of an application
or from issuing incorrect ad-hoc SQL. The following
information may aid in determining the deadlock:
Deadlock graph:
                       ---------Blocker(s)--------  ---------Waiter(s)---------
Resource Name          process session holds waits  process session holds waits
TX-00010012-0102905b        54     474     X             52     256           X
TX-000a0005-00a30961        52     256     X             54     474           X

session 474: DID 0001-0036-00000002 session 256: DID 0001-0034-00000002
session 256: DID 0001-0034-00000002 session 474: DID 0001-0036-00000002
Rows waited on:
Session 256: obj - rowid = 00013181 - AAATGBAAzAABtPTAAI
  (dictionary objn - 78209, file - 51, block - 447443, slot - 8)
Session 474: obj - rowid = 00013181 - AAATGBAAzAABtPUAAJ
  (dictionary objn - 78209, file - 51, block - 447444, slot - 9)
Information on the OTHER waiting sessions:
Session 256:
  pid=52 serial=58842 audsid=43375302 user: 106/B2B_ISINTERNAL
  O/S info: user: admwmt, term: spl099wmt04.compucom.local, ospid: , machine: spl099wmt04.compucom.local/10.16.0.41
            program: JDBC Connect Client
Current SQL Statement:
SELECT ID, TARGET, NEXT, STATE FROM TAB1 
WHERE NEXT=(SELECT MIN(NEXT) FROM TAB1 WHERE (TARGET='$any') AND ( STATE = 0))
AND (TARGET='$any')
AND (STATE = 0) FOR UPDATE
End of information on OTHER waiting sessions.
===================================================
```

Is there any way to avoid this? Rewriting the Query or Indexing?

Comment: Removed the sql-server tag because the question pertains to Oracle

Answer (score 0):

I think the reason can be that you are actually selecting the same table twice with FOR UPDATE clause, once in the main query and once in subquery.

Comment: Yes, I need that sub-query to select the min(NEXT). The query is to select a row which has minimum NEXT (timestamp) and target/state as specified in the input.

Comment: I'm not an Oracle guru but the concepts are the same with other RDBMs.

A deadlock is two competing processes waiting for each other to complete before continuing. In your case it looks like sessionid 256 is competing with 474. One of those sessions is trying to select a bunch of rows and obtain an UPDATE lock. Not sure if the message is displaying the other but it's possibly the same statement.

You need to change your transactional process from the start where you are doing a select to the update. It will be helpful if you post your entire procedure from start to end.

Comment: I have java method() that can be invoked by multiple threads. The Java method does the following transaction. 1. Get connection (auto commit false). 2. Execute the above SELECT FOR UPDATE query. 3. If there is a row, then do some business logic and update the NEXT (timestamp) column and Commit.

Answer (score 0):

**Update**

Instead of trying to guess exactly how Oracle retrieves rows and force a plan, it may be easier to use one of the available [`UPDATE FOR` locking features](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/statements_10002.htm#SQLRF55372).

`NOWAIT` or `SKIP LOCKED` should be able to fix the problem.  Although with `NOWAIT` you would probably need to add some application logic to retry after an error.

---

Since there are bind variables there may be multiple execution plans for the same SQL statement.  This is normally a good thing, for example think about a query like this: `select * from tab where status = ?`.  A full table scan would work best for a popular status, and an index scan would work better for a rare status.  But if one plan uses an index and one uses a table, the same statement will retrieve resources in a different order, potentially causing a deadlock.

Forcing the statement to always use the same plan will prevent the deadlocks.

First, you will want to confirm my theory about multiple execution plans is correct.  Look for multiple rows in this query, specifically look for different `plan_hash_value`s for the same SQL_ID.

```
select child_number, plan_hash_value, gv$sql.*
from gv$sql
where sql_text like '%NEXT=(SELECT%';
```

Then it's a matter of forcing the statements to always use the same plan.  One simple way is to find the outline that fixes a specific plan, and use the same set of hints for both statements.  Hopefully the forced plan will still run well for all sets of bind variables.

```
select *
from table(dbms_xplan.display_cursor(
    sql_id => '<SQL_ID from above>',
    cursor_child_no => <child_number from above>,
    format => '+outline')
);
```

Comment: Hi, I got multiple rows but have same plan_hash_value. When query for the outline. Its shows: Plan hash value: 3867517551
 -------------------------------
| Id  | Operation             |
-------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT      |
|   1 |  FOR UPDATE           |
|   2 |   BUFFER SORT         |
|*  3 |    TABLE ACCESS FULL  |
|   4 |     SORT AGGREGATE    |
|*  5 |      TABLE ACCESS FULL|
-------------------------------

Comment: Maybe the other plan aged out of the shared pool.  You can also look for multiple plans in AWR.  First make sure that you have enough history, check `select * from dba_hist_snapshot;` that it extends to the date the deadlock occurred.  If it goes back far enough, then run `select * from table(dbms_xplan.display_awr(sql_id => '<sql id above>'));`.  This will show if there are any historical `plan_hash_value`s.  If there's really only one plan then this might be related to my old question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9216150/409172).

Comment: Will this query help ?  SELECT * FROM TAB1 WHERE TXID = (SELECT TXID FROM (SELECT * FROM TAB1 WHERE STATE=? AND TARGET=? ORDER BY NEXT ASC) WHERE ROWNUM = 1) FOR UPDATE